# Ejs passed variable not showing

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using express framework in node js.
for page rendering i use ejs.
given below route i passed 3 variable doctors title or loggined user id

```
router.get('/doctors/:id',passportConf.isAuthenticated, function(req,res,next){
    Doctor.find({category:req.params.id})
    .populate("category")
    .exec(function(err, doctors){
        if (err) return next (err);
        res.render('main/doctor', {doctors: doctors, title:'doctors', id: req.user._id})
    })
});
```

now problem is when i access these variable like this then i get my variable data

```
<%= doctors[i]._id%> or <%= title %> or <%= id%>
```

but when i acces these variable data in if statment then id data give nothing

i tried this in if statment 
user id is 5cfaa0e32e21cb3c88885260
if (doctor[i]._id != '5cfaa0e32e21cb3c88885260')
then my code worked fine
if (id != '5cfaa0e32e21cb3c88885260')
thene my code not work
my ejs code
                `<% for(i=0; i<doctors.length; i++) {%>
                                <small><%= doctors[i].category.name%></small>
                            <ul>
                                <% if (id != '5cfaa0e32e21cb3c88885260') {%>
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="doctor_id" value="<%= doctors[i]._id%>">
                                    <button class="btn_1 medium" type="submit">Book now</button>
                                </form>
                                <%}%>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <%}%>`

Comment: post your ejs code

Comment: ejs code added check now

Comment: it works after for loop closing